# Replacing nesting of text tags such as <b> with <span> in an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with an inner HTML which looks a lot like:

```
<b>First <span class="red">se</span></b><span class="red">cond third fo</span>urth fift<span class="large">h sixth</span>
```

This markup can contain any text formatting tags since it is the output of a text-editing library.

For something I am working on, I need to remove any nesting that exists. So, ideally, the above markup string should become:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">First</span> <span style="font-weight:bold;color:red">se</span><span style="font-weight:bold">cond third fo</span><span>urth fift</span><span style="font-size:20px;">h sixth</span>
```

To give some context, the markup at the top is the output of Wysihtml5 text editor which is pretty useful but I need the markup to be similar to the second one to be able

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('b').each(function(){ 
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(this).replaceWith('<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red">' + text + '</span>');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uQyL3/1/

Comment: It doesn't look like "First" is supposed to be red.

Comment: It is. All the text that was in between `<b></b>` tags should now be in between `<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red"></span>` tags.

Comment: I don't know where you read that, but in the question, the OP writes that the expected outcome should start with `<span style="font-weight:bold">First</span>`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was simply trying to write a function that would replace any `<b></b>` tags with spans, which can of course be styled however you want. Maybe I misunderstood the question.